# How to make NodeJS addon show property info like a regular object

Tags: node.js, v8, add-on

I have an addon created with several prototypes but when I try to `console.log( myinstace )` the're no properties listed. `{}` is the result. The desired outcome would be something like below. How do I make this happen?

addon.cc

```
Local<FunctionTemplate> self = FunctionTemplate::New(New);
self->PrototypeTemplate()->Set(
    String::NewSymbol("Method")
,   FunctionTemplate::New(method)
);
```

app.js

```
console.log( myinstance ); // desired { Method : [Function: Method ] }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `self->PrototypeTemplate()->Set` and not `self->Set`? `console.log` does not print out prototype chain values.

Comment: It's in the addons doc. http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html, but I see I doont need the `PrototypeTemplate()` call, still no log output. with just `self->set()`

Comment: Okay, the new line you added makes it clearer that you are working with a constructor function. This has nothing to do with C++, this is just the fact that `console.log()` only displays `own` properties, it does not show prototype chain properties. You see the same behavior with `function MyObj(){} MyObj.prototype.Method = function Method(){}; console.log(new MyObj())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general using `inspect` from the `util` package will give the deepest examination of an objects properties and prototypes.

```
const util = require('util')
var mod = require(...)
console.log(util.inspect(mod))
```